# Bash script loop with zero paddings for the numbers

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, brace-expansion, bash-expansion

So I need to repeatedly try submitting a 4 digit number to a port on the local host, and then evaluate the response I get from the port if it contains a specific string, which I do with `grep`. I used something like `echo {0000...9999} | nc localhost port`. However, I cannot get this nice sequence expansion that I get from this command to work in a bash script. How could I go about writing a bash script for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use within a `for-loop` like following:

```
for i in {0001..9999}; do
    grep -q 'specificString' <<<"$(nc localhost $i)" && \
    echo "found on $i" || echo "not found on $i";
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For shells that does not support brace expansions, or that does not preserve zero padding:

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -le 9999 ]; do
    printf '%04d\n' "$i"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done | nc ...other options... | grep ...etc...
```